# How to open file with valid content/characters

Tags: python, file, encoding, iso-8859-1

I want to open a file in Python with code:

```
with open('file_mld.mld', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as mld: #   ISO-8859-1
    print(mld.read())
```

I'm getting the `io.TextIOWrapper` object.

I use `latin-1` and `ISO-8859-1` encoding, every time I get the result: `6 @ UÔ ‹À0> @ UÔ‹ À0> @ 2Ì ‹ÀSF @ 2Ì‹ ÀSF @ È ‹ÀwN @`

How can I make content more understandable?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your file it's hard to give an answer. Have you checked other [encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)?

Comment: @Tranbi I do not know much also about file format, I tried encodings that you sent but without success.